# No USB tethering possible with Galaxy S3

Tags: android, samsung, tethering

I have a **Galaxy S3** (SGH-I747; Android 4.1.1; AT&T) and a **Galaxy Note** (SGH-I717; Android 4.1.2; AT&T).  They are both on the same AT&T family plan, which **includes the tethering/wi-fi hot-spot** (i.e. no need to root the phone).

The wi-fi hot-spot works with both phones to connect my laptop (Ubuntu 12.10; Asus A53E).  But I can only use the USB tethering with the Galaxy Note.  Any problems with the GS3 I don't know of?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem using :

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tetherunlocker

Open the app, click on "unlock tethering", wait for the video completion, and magically tether works, try it and le me know.